# How to get correct intellisense with useClass provider

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a class that extends native angular service, and used class provider to override it.

Extended service

```
@Injectable()
export class ExtendedFormBuilder extends FormBuilder {
  control(
    formState: any,
    validator: any = null,
    asyncValidator: any = null,
    errorConfig: any = null
  ): ExtendedFormControl {
    return new ExtendedFormControl(formState, validator, asyncValidator, errorConfig);
  }
}
```

part of `app.module`

```
{
  provide: FormBuilder,
  useClass: ExtendedFormBuilder
}
```

However intellisense in my component still thinks I'm using old `FormBuilder` class.

```
this.fb.control('Joe', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(2)
], null, { // Error! `FormBuilder.control` takes only 3 params, not 4.
  minLength: 2
})
```

Is there any way to get around this, with usage of provide class?

One thing to note, is that code is working. What is not working is the typescript type checking, that is making my code unable to build.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#useclass

Answer (score 1):

The static type information only allows to derive `FormBuilder`. If you "know", at runtime it will actually be an `ExtendedFormBuilder`, you can cast it

```
class MyComponent {
  ExtendedFormBuilder fb;
  constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.fb = fb as ExtendedFormBuilder;
  }
```